# Refresh ListObject QueryTable without select

Tags: excel, vba, listobject

I need to update a QueryTable from another Workbook using VBA, which is stored in a veryHidden Worksheet.

If i check the Makro Record function it makes this:

```
Sub MakroRefreshPlanung()

    Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

End Sub
```

But because of the veryHidden status of the Worksheet, i can't use a select statement.

I try this instead:

```
Sub MakroRefreshPlanung()

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Abfrage von Planung").ListObject(Abfrage_von_Planung).QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

End Sub
```

But get the error message:

```
Laufzeitfehler '438':

Objekt unterstützt diese Eigenschaft oder Methode nicht
```

How can i refresh it without select?

Thanks a lot

Comment: `.ListObject` should be `.ListObjects`. What is `Abfrage_von_Planung`?

Comment: Abfrage_von_Planung is the table name

If i change from `.ListObject` to `.ListObjects` i get the error message:

`Laufzeitfehler '9': Index außerhalb des gültigen Bereichs`

Comment: Is `Abfrage_von_Planung` a variable? Did you mean `.ListObjects("Abfrage_von_Planung")`  ?

Comment: There is something wrong with how you are naming either worksheet, the Table or both. Do they both have the same name?

Comment: Hey Together,

the Worksheet Name is "Abfrage von Planung"
the Table Name is "Abfrage_von_Planung"

If I use the Code `MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Abfrage von Planung").ListObjects(1).Name` it shows the name "Abfrage_von_Planung"

For a better understanding, i changed the names now:

Sheet = "Abfrage von Planung"
Table = "table_planning"
Query = "get_planning"

so the new Code is:
```ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Abfrage von Planung").ListObjects(table_planning).QueryTable.Refresh```

but the error is again `Laufzeitfehler '9': Index außerhalb des gültigen Bereichs`

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Abfrage von Planung").ListObjects("table_planning")`

Comment: @TimWilliams, sometimes it can be so easy :D that works. Thank you!

Comment: FYI if you always use `Option Explicit` then it will point out problems like this (undeclared variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

`ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Abfrage von Planung").ListObjects(table_planning)`

`table_planning` is treated as an undeclared and unassigned variable.

If you mean to use that as a string literal which is the name of the listobject, then enclose it in quotes:

`ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Abfrage von Planung").ListObjects("table_planning")`